# Determine Sender of Envelope from Rest 2.0 API

Tags: docusignapi

I might be missing something obvious, but how does one determine who sent an envelope when using the Rest 2.0 API?

I see that the `/accounts/{accountId}/search_folders/{search_folder}` call returns folder_items that contains `ownerName` and `senderName`, but no other references to being able to get that info without doing a folder search.

Currently, i'm making a search for envelopes using /envelopes with some parameters and I get back the envelopeID, but can't seem to find a way to use that to get the sender.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: To access the API?  vb.net or c#, depending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve this information by using the following REST API call:

**Get Envelope Audit Events**

This returns the events for this envelope (including who sent, etc).

**URL:**

```
/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/audit_events
```

**Formats:**

```
XML, JSON
```

**HTTP Method:**

```
GET
```

---

Check out page 127 of the REST API PDF guide for more info:
http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "GET Envelope Audit Events" operation to determine the sender of an Envelope.  The call is simply:

```
GET https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/audit_events
```

(See pages 127-128 of the REST API guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf) for details about this operation.)